# SimpleModal popup doesn't center until browser is resized

Tags: jquery, position, simplemodal

I'm using the [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) plugin to popup a post but it doesn't center horizontally until  the browser is re-sized. I set the top position to "0" but want it centered horizontally when called. Here is the function I use to activate it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('a.postpopup').live('click', function(){
            var id = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
    jQuery('<div id="ajax-popup"></div>').hide().appendTo('body').load('http://fameordie.com/ajax-handler/?id='+id).modal({
               opacity:90,
           position: ["0%"],
               overlayClose:true
            });
            return false;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want fixed modal use this:
and better way is remove containerCss and add top and right into modal css

for : top,right :

```
$(function() {
jQuery('a.postpopup').live('click', function(){
            var id = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
    jQuery('<div id="ajax-popup"></div>').hide().appendTo('body').load('http://fameordie.com/ajax-handler/?id='+id).modal({
               opacity:90,
               autoPosition:false,
           containerCss:{top:12,right:12,display:"none",position:"fixed",zIndex:1002},
               overlayClose:true
            });
            return false;
 });
});
```

for top,center:

```
$(function() {
jQuery('a.postpopup').live('click', function(){
            var id = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
    jQuery('<div id="ajax-popup"></div>').hide().appendTo('body').load('http://fameordie.com/ajax-handler/?id='+id).modal({
               opacity:90,
               position:['0',]
            });
            return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: Ok how can I make it center horizontally? I need top:0 and centered horizontally.

Comment: @Pollux Khafra check top,center; it's exactly is same as you want

Comment: I gave the container a width of 100% and then gave the pop box inside of it `position:relative` and `margin:0 auto` and that did the trick. Is there a better way?

Comment: @PolluxKhafra i use Firefox 12 and test second way , it's work correctly, you can visit [osx demo link](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos), click on osx demo, it's top 0 and centered vertically